# How to close the current tab using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to close the current tab using javascript. But i did not got any solutions. I searched the whole internet for this and some of the post suggest below solution.

```
 $("#click").click("click", function(element) {
     window.top.close();
 });
```

But after clicking the button getting `Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.` as a warning in the console. Is there any possible way to close the current tab which are not opened by any script?

Comment: Assuming you're running the JS logic *within* the opened tab, then `window.close()` will work. However, as the error states, you cannot close another tab which was not opened through code.

Comment: Use `$(selector).on('click', function(e))` rather than  `$("#click").click("click", function(e)`

Comment: i am using jQuery 1.3. I think $(selector).on('click', function(e)) was Introduced in jQuery 2.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close

> This method can only be called on windows that were opened by a script using the Window.open() method. If the window was not opened by a script, an error similar to this one appears in the console: Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script.

Comment: got the clarity, thank you